# Array returns "Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "Candidate" or "candidate"?"

Tags: solidity

when trying to set up an array of structs i get an error that says "Undeclared identifier. Did you mean "Candidate" or "candidate"?"

Ive tried to create an empty array by writing

```
uint[] memory candidate;
```

and

```
bytes[] memory candidate
```

above the function in which i'm getting errors to instantiate it. However, this doesn't work either and gives errors. It does not compile.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.0;

contract Election {
    string public candidate;

    struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

    mapping(uint => Candidate) candidate;

    uint public candidatesCount;

    function createCandidate(string storage name ) private {
        candidatesCount ++;
        candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, name, 0);
    }  

    function addCandidates () public {
        createCandidate("Candidate1");
        createCandidate("Candidate2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
    mapping(uint => Candidate) candidate;
```

to

```
   mapping(uint => Candidate) candidates;
```

and

```
    function createCandidate(string storage name ) private
```

to

```
    function createCandidate(string memory name ) private
```

Comment: Thank you! is the first line how you instantiate an array?

Comment: Here you are using mapping not array. `Undeclared identifier` was shown due to variable name mismatch in line 12 and 18. I am guessing its a typo.